# Creating a ehcache cache in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, ehcache

I am having trouble creating a simple [ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/) cache in Kotlin. I am trying to keep the cache as generic as possible so the key value pairs are the generics `Pos` and `Move`.

```
import org.ehcache.CacheManager
import org.ehcache.Cache
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder

class Main<reified Pos, reified Move> {

    val cm : CacheManager?
    val solvedPositions : Cache<Pos, Move>?

    init {
            cm = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder() 
                               .withCache("solved", CacheConfigurationBuilder<Pos, Move>()
                               .withResourcePools(ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(10)))
                               .buildConfig(Class<Pos>::class.java, Class<Move>::class.java)
                               .build(true); 
            solvedPositions = cm.getCache("solved", Class<Pos>::class.java, Class<Move>::class.java);
    }


    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    }
}
```

Running this program gives the following error messages:

```
e: /Users/christophersumnicht/CacheIssue/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt: (7, 12): Only type parameters of inline functions can be reified
e: /Users/christophersumnicht/CacheIssue/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt: (7, 25): Only type parameters of inline functions can be reified
e: /Users/christophersumnicht/CacheIssue/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt: (14, 53): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
private constructor CacheConfigurationBuilder<K : Any!, V : Any!>(keyType: Class<Pos!>!, valueType: Class<Move!>!, resourcePools: ResourcePools!) defined in org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder
private constructor CacheConfigurationBuilder<K : Any!, V : Any!>(other: CacheConfigurationBuilder<Pos!, Move!>!) defined in org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder
e: /Users/christophersumnicht/CacheIssue/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt: (16, 45): Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal
e: /Users/christophersumnicht/CacheIssue/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt: (16, 69): Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal
e: /Users/christophersumnicht/CacheIssue/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt: (18, 53): Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal
e: /Users/christophersumnicht/CacheIssue/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt: (18, 77): Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal
:compileKotlin FAILED
```

Note that I have also removed `reified` and I get similar errors to this. How can I resolve these errors?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to to pass a `Class` instance as a constructor as follows:

```
import org.ehcache.CacheManager
import org.ehcache.Cache
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder

class Main<Pos, Move>(p: Class<Pos>, m: Class<Move>) {

    val cm : CacheManager?
    val solvedPositions : Cache<Class<Pos>, Class<Move>>?

    init {
        cm = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder() 
                                .withCache("solved", CacheConfigurationBuilder<Pos, Move>()
                                .withResourcePools(ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(10)))
                                .buildConfig(p.javaClass, m.javaClass)
                                .build(true); 
        solvedPositions = cm.getCache("solved", p.javaClass, m.javaClass);
    }


    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I still have issues with the private constructors:

```
:compileKotlin
e: /Users/christophersumnicht/CacheIssue/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt: (14, 54): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
private constructor CacheConfigurationBuilder<K : Any!, V : Any!>(keyType: Class<Pos!>!, valueType: Class<Move!>!, resourcePools: ResourcePools!) defined in org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder
private constructor CacheConfigurationBuilder<K : Any!, V : Any!>(other: CacheConfigurationBuilder<Pos!, Move!>!) defined in org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder
:compileKotlin FAILED
```

Comment: `reified` can only be used on type parameters of inline functions, not classes. You need to pass the Class or KClass instances as constructor parameters.

Comment: @yole I have also tried a version without reified. It omits the first two errors but still gives the other errors.

Comment: You need to pass the Class or KClass instances as constructor parameters.

Comment: @yole: Ok, I have tried to do that but still get some issues with private constructors. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Which version of EHCache are you using? I couldn't find 'CacheManagerBuilder' on my classpath and I do have EHCache as well.

Comment: CacheManagerBuilder is version 3

Comment: @RafalG. I am using 3.3.0 to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue left with the `CacheConfigurationBuilder`: it does not have a public constructor and you need instead to use:

```
CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(keyClass, valueClass, ResourcePools);
```

I believe the form you are trying to use existed in the early builds of 3.0.0 but was removed before release as it allowed to try building cache configurations with missing mandatory fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just for an entire working example here is what ended up working:

```
import org.ehcache.CacheManager
import org.ehcache.Cache
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder

class Main<Pos, Move>(p: Class<Pos>, m: Class<Move>) {

    val cm : CacheManager?
    val solvedPositions : Cache<Class<Pos>, Class<Move>>?

    init {
        cm = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder() 
                                .withCache("solved", 
                                CacheConfigurationBuilder
                                .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(p.javaClass, m.javaClass, ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(10))).build()
        solvedPositions = cm.getCache("solved", p.javaClass, m.javaClass)
    }


    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    }
}
```